# Correct zoom in-out percentage range to test responsiveness on different browsers on different devices

Tags: html, css, responsive, responsiveness

I am using Google Chrome and  to test the resposiveness of the webapp I am working on. As on date today I have:

1. Google Chrome - Version 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) (64-bit)
2. Mozilla Firefox - Version 84.0.2 (64-bit)

Chrome offers zoom percentage 25-500% while Mozilla offers 30-300%.

I am noticing these percentage ranges for a while.

**Question:**
What is the correct range of min and max percentage to test the responsiveness of the css/html for majority of devices ranging from wide screens to hand held devices - say curved ultra wide screen desktop monitors and ultra high resolution laptops to all the way down to mobile phones of iphone8 size screens or similar?

I am asking as now a days in UI/UX world every business and project management team is concerned about the responsiveness of application's pages on all screen-sizes of the devices. And we may not have all the devices handy to get even a "fake" confidence how the application will behave on different screen sizes. Our development machines are all windows based and do not have Safari at all. So now the question becomes, is there some way we can rely on a specific browser's zoom in-out percentage range to get an idea of the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the **Device Toolbar within Chrome developer tools**. You can adjust the **viewport** size to simulate different devices.

[image]

This works well when you need to simulate devices that are **larger** (and smaller) than your current screen.

My current laptop display resolution is **1920x1080**. If I want to accurately test a device that is **larger**, let's say **2048x1536**, I can adjust the viewport width and height to 2048x1536 within Chrome's developer tools:
[image]

Now look at a screenshot from BrowserStack that is showing a real 2048x1536 screen size and notice that it matches perfectly:
[image]

Comment: @AjayKumar, good to hear! You can also add custom devices within the Device Toolbar which allows you to save certain width/height combos. Ex, For desktop testing, I added devices with these values: 3840x2160, 1920x1080, 1440x900, 1366x786, 1280x720.